# pandas convert dict nested unbalance dict into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I parsed XML data into dict. The dict has following form:

```
{'id': 'Q1',
'subject': 'Massage oil',
'question': 'Where I can buy good oil for massage?',
'comments': {},
'related': {'Q1_R1': {'rid': 'Q1_R1',
'rel_subject': 'massage oil',
'rel_question': 'is there any place i can find scented massage oils in qatar?',
'rel_givenRelevance': 'PerfectMatch',
'rel_givenRank': '1',
'rel_comments': {'Q1_R1_C1': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C1',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 01:40:05',
 'com_username': 'anonymous',
 'comment': 'Yes. It is right behind Kahrama in the National area.',
 'com_isTraining': True},
'Q1_R1_C2': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C2',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 01:42:59',
 'com_username': 'sognabodl',
 'comment': 'whats the name of the shop?',
 'com_isTraining': True},
'Q1_R1_C3': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C3',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 01:44:09',
 'com_username': 'anonymous',
 'comment': "It's called Naseem Al-Nadir. Right next to the Smartlink shop. You'll find the chinese salesgirls at affordable prices there.",
 'com_isTraining': True},
'Q1_R1_C4': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C4',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 01:58:39',
 'com_username': 'sognabodl',
 'comment': 'dont want girls;want oil',
 'com_isTraining': True},
'Q1_R1_C5': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C5',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 01:59:55',
 'com_username': 'anonymous',
 'comment': "Try Both ;) I'am just trying to be helpful. On a serious note - Please go there. you'll find what you are looking for.",
 'com_isTraining': True},
'Q1_R1_C6': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C6',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 02:02:53',
 'com_username': 'lawa',
 'comment': 'you mean oil and filter both',
 'com_isTraining': True},
'Q1_R1_C7': {'cid': 'Q1_R1_C7',
 'com_date': '2010-08-27 02:04:29',
 'com_username': 'anonymous',
 'comment': "Yes Lawa...you couldn't be more right LOL",
 'com_isTraining': True}},
'rel_featureVector': [],
'rel_isTraining': True}},
'featureVector': [],
'isTraining': True}
```

General like:

```
 {ID     : Q1,
  ...
  related:{
          Q1_R1 :{
                rid:Q1_R1,
                ....
                rel_comments:{
                        Q1_R1_C1: {
                                cid: Q1_R1_C1,
                                ....
                                  }
                        ....
                        Q1_R1_C10
                              }
         ...
        Q1_R10
         }
 ...
 ID : 100   
 }
```

I want turn it to:

```
  ID  ...  question rid    ...  rel_question   cid        .... comment
  Q1  ...  1234     Q1_R1  ...  5678         Q1_R1_c1     .... 90
  Q1  ...  1234     Q1_R1  ...  5678         Q1_R1_c2     .... 92
  Q1  ...  1234     Q1_R1  ...  5678         Q1_R1_c3     .... 93
      ..........................................
  Q100 ... 1234   Q100_R10  ... 5678         Q100_R10_c13  ....465
```

I try to flatten this dict, but I get `rid(Q1_R1 ...Q100_R10 )` and `cid( Q1_R1_c1     ... Q100_R10_c13 )` as columns, is there any way to do this?

This semeval 2016 subtask 1'data, I think use dataframe function such as apply..
can improve the performance. For example, to calculate how much similar are `Q1` question and `Q1_R1_C1` comment ?...

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the structure of your dict and generate another dict that has the correct structure so that pandas can make the desired DataFrame out of it. Here only for some of the columns, but you should get the point:

```
df_dict = {
    'id': [],
    'subject': [],
    'question': [],
    'rid': [],
    'rel_question': [],
    'cid': [],
    'comment': []
 }
for rid in mydict['related']:
    for cid in mydict['related'][rid]['rel_comments']:
        df_dict['id'].append(mydict['id'])
        df_dict['subject'].append(mydict['subject'])
        df_dict['question'].append(mydict['question'])
        df_dict['rid'].append(rid)
        df_dict['rel_question'].append(mydict['related'][rid]['rel_question'])
        df_dict['cid'].append(cid)
        df_dict['comment'].append(mydict['related'][rid]['rel_comments'][cid]['comment'])

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, I'd be thankful if you'd [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.